# Select Unique rows from the data (not having mutiple Key values and Year) using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

The incoming  data Looks like this:

```
ID  Key Year  
1   2288    2013  
1   2288    2014  
1   2831    2012  
1   3723    2012  
1   5005    2012
```

The o/p should be

```
ID  Key     Year  
1   2288    2013  
1   2288    2014
```

If there are multiple "Key" Values" for the same ID and Year then those rows should be eliminated.

Comment: What's your elimination criteria? Which key do you want to keep from the multiple values for the same ID and Year?

Comment: Editted the question, the O/p should not have 2012 rows since there are multiple key values for the same Year and ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by ID and Year.

```
SELECT ID, MIN(KEY), YEAR
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID, YEAR
HAVING COUNT(KEY)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window Function` to get the `min` key value in each `year` when it is duplicated.

```
Select ID, Key, Year from 
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by Id,Year order by key) Rn
)a
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Select 
  ID, Key, Year 
from 
  table
group by
  ID, Year
having
  count(*) = 1
```